# Can you scale the UI in Visual Studio Community 2019 (like in VS Code ctrl+/ctrl-)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I find everything to be a bit too small for my liking whenever I'm working on my 1080p, 14" laptop and have been trying to find a way to scale up EVERYTHING (text, icons, etc), but somehow the only thing I can find is scaling up the font in the editor or other windows, one by one, inside of Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors.

This has to be possible, right? What you get when hitting [ctrl +]/[ctrl -] in VS Code is essentialy what I'm trying to achieve, except in VSC2019.